# Объединение массива PHP

Tags: php, рекурсия, merge

Имеется массив вида:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'RABBIT_MQ' => array(
            'LOGIN' => 'ADMIN'
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'RABBIT_MQ' => array(
            'PORT' => array(
                'TEST' => array(15672)
            )
        )
    ),
    2 => array(
        'RABBIT_MQ' => array(
            'PASSWORD' => 'ADMIN'
        )
    )
);
```

Мне необходимо получить массив вида:

```
$array = array(
    'RABBIT_MQ' => array(
        'LOGIN' => 'ADMIN',
        'PORT' => array(
            'TEST' => 15672
        ),
        'PASSWORD' => 'ADMIN'
    )
);
```

**Как это сделать, учитывая то, что вложенность массива не известна. Может быть и 5 уровней и 10.**

Answer (score 0):

в целом почти идентичный результат достигается с помощью

```
$result = array_merge_recursive(...$array)
```

различие в `'test' => 12672` и не ясно по какому принципу у вас массив преобразовался в число.